# Rxjs подписка только на последний запрос

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, request, rxjs

Как правильней и лучше всего реализовать подписку только на последний запрос?
Например:

1. Отправляем запрос. Он обрабатывается долго.
2. Отправляем повторно второй запрос и получаем сразу ответ. Обрабатываем его в subscribe.
3. Вдруг прилетает ответ на первый запрос и его уже обрабатывать не нужно.

Сделал так (вырезка из Angular)

```
private lastRequestTime = Date.now();
getData() {
  const date = Date.now();
  this.lastRequestTime = date;
  this.dataService
    .getData()
    .pipe(
      takeWhile(() => this.lastRequestTime === date),
    )
    .subscribe(response => {
      // do something
    });
}
```

Но думаю есть более лаконичный подход.
Как правильней?

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/last

Comment: Если я правильно понял - суть от этого не особо изменится. Просто будет вместо takeWhile last с условием. Может есть еще варианты?

Comment: попробуйте https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap

Comment: Возникает вопрос, почему нельзя дожидаться первого запроса, пока он не упадет или не вернет значение? Возможно стоит подумать в сторону смены поведения? Стоит добавить побольше контекста задачи, чтобы было понимание)

Answer (score 0):

Если вам необходимо отлавливать последний запрос воспользуйтесь Debounce

https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/debounce

Comment: Или еще проще, вставьте в свой pipe debouncetime, с указанием задержки в мс

 https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debouncetime

Answer (score 0):

Вообще стандартная стратегия `HttpClient` - это канселить `PENDING REQUEST`. Если это какая-то своя тема на `rxjs`, то простого `take(1)` будет достаточно, если надо только первое значение из стрима.
Опять же, если ваша `getData` состоит из пачки разных запросов, и нужен только первый, можно заюзать `race`.

```
return race(
  timer(5000).pipe(mapTo('slow')),
  timer(2000).pipe(mapTo('faster')),
  timer(1000).pipe(mapTo('fastest')) // подписка создастся только на этот стрим, остальные игнорятся
)
```